# iPhone - Make Text Field with Floating Number that Responds to Swipes

Tags: iphone, floating-point, uitextfield, touch, swipe

How can I make a text field (or something that looks similar) with a number in it, which you can increase or decrease by touching it and swiping your finger up (increase) or down (decrease).

How it would work: There is a texfield with 0.0 on it. You touch it, and move your finger down. Then you see the value decrease as you move your finger further. When you stop moving your finger, the value doesn't change.

How could this be done in Objective-C?

Comment: A `UISlider` that is hidden / transparent should do the trick

Comment: But then it would be only touchable from within the textfield (or a view?), is that even possible? Because I don't want it to interfere with the rest of the interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is quite big, so I decided to put some sample code on [github](http://github.com/alexcoplan/DragLabels).

To cater for multiple labels, we're first going to subclass `UILabel`, to add a property called `dragging`. We're gong to call the class `DragLabel`.

**DragLabel.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DragLabel : UILabel {
    BOOL dragging;
}

@property (assign) BOOL dragging;

@end
```

**DragLabel.m**

```
#import "DragLabel.h"

@implementation DragLabel
@synthesize dragging;

@end
```

---

**Interface Builder**

Now you need to drag three labels into the view in IB, and change all their classes to `DragLabel`. Make sure you do this *before* creating the outlets.

[image: Class Change in IB]

After doing this, hook all the outlets up to your .m and .h. In my instance, I gave them names of label1, label2 and label3.

---

Now we have our label class and interface set up, its time to write the code for the view controller.

Your **Controller.h** should look like this. I called it **DragViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DragLabel.h"

@interface DragViewController : UIViewController {
    DragLabel *label1;
    DragLabel *label2;
    DragLabel *label3;

    NSArray *draglabels;        
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet DragLabel *label1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet DragLabel *label2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet DragLabel *label3;
```

Your **Controller.m** should look like this. I called it **DragViewController.m**

```
#import "DragViewController.h"

@implementation DragViewController
@synthesize label1;
@synthesize label2;
@synthesize label3;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [label1 release];
    [label2 release];
    [label3 release];
    [draglabels release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    draglabels = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:label1, label2, label3, nil];
    for (DragLabel *label in draglabels) {
        label.dragging = NO;
    }

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)movedLabel:(DragLabel *)label touchloc:(CGPoint)touchloc {
    float val = (label.center.y - touchloc.y)/10;
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g",val];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint touchloc = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    for (DragLabel *label in draglabels) {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(label.frame, touchloc)) {
            label.dragging = YES;
            [self movedLabel:label touchloc:touchloc];
        }
    }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (DragLabel *label in draglabels) {
        if (label.dragging) {
            CGPoint touchloc = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
            [self movedLabel:label touchloc:touchloc];
        }
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (DragLabel *label in draglabels) {
        label.dragging = NO;
    }
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setLabel1:nil];
    [self setLabel2:nil];
    [self setLabel3:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

@end
```

---

**One last thing**

To adjust the scale so it ranges from 0 to 1, only when the user drags above the label, re-implement `movedLabel` like this:

```
- (void)movedLabel:(DragLabel *)label touchloc:(CGPoint)touchloc {
    float ydif = label.center.y-touchloc.y;
    float maxheight = 100;
    if (ydif > 0) {
        if (ydif <= maxheight) label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g",ydif/maxheight];
        else label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g",maxheight];
    }
    else label.text = @"0.0";
}
```

Comment: This looks really good, though would it also be possible with 3 of those text fields?

Comment: Hmm, it keeps giving me: use of undeclared identifier 'label'...
Also, how would I subclass UILabel? I'm not sure how to do that... I think it has to be something like: ` UILabel *MyLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];` but where would I put that?

Comment: I haven't tested the new code I'll try it now and update if there's a problem.

Comment: Wow! It works perfectly!!!!!
Thank you so much!! I see you used float val = (label.center.y - touchloc.y)/10; to determine the float, right? I'll have a look if I can tweak that some more, as I want the value to go from 0.0 to 1.0

Comment: Modifying the scale is easy as pie, thank you so very much for this!

Comment: I also wanted to control different variables with the labels, and I did that by using the label.center.x to determine which label I'm controlling:
`if (label.center.x == 204 ) { bluecolor=val; }`

Comment: you could just set the labels tag in IB - it's probably safer

Comment: hmmm, I thought I couldn't find that property on the label object, but, I'll check again!

Comment: That tag? Wow, I was actually thinking of something entirely different (the identity label). Thanks for that! (I didn't get the time to look at it btw)

Just one more question btw: let's say I want to merge this with another app using the TouchesBegan function, would it then be possible to somehow sense if I am or am not touching the labels in the beginning? So I can then split the function into the label value changing part, and the other part (from the other app)